# How to output date as follows 8 December 2013 in C++

Tags: c++

I get  the following error message ...

> Error 1
>     error C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Any help would be appreciated.

```
const char EOL( '\n');  
    int main()                                                      //draw Xmas tree
    {   
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm *ltm = localtime(&now);



    cout << "Damon Reynolds Tut 1V"<< ltm->tm_mday  << " " 
         << 1 + ltm->tm_mon << " " << 1900 + ltm->tm_year;          
        getValidHeigth();                                               //call procedure
        cout << EOL;                                                    //then output a new line
        drawBranches();                                                 //call procedure
        drawTrunk();                                                    //call procedure

        cout << EOL;                                                    //then output a new line
        system( "PAUSE");                                               //hold the screen until a key is pressed
        return( 0);
    }
```

Comment: You should be outputting `'\n'` for a newline.

Comment: @chris or `std::endl`

Comment: @godel9, Only if you need to flush it as well, and then you're probably better off explicitly doing a newline and a `std::flush`.

Comment: @chris: It's certainly a round-about way to do it, but doesn't `const char EOL('\n');` mean that `EOL` _is_ `'\n'`?  In any case, I think the answer is in the error message:  Look up `localtime_s` and use it in place of `localtime`.  And if you want to print the month _name_ instead of the month _number_, declare an array of month names and use `ltm->tm_mon` to index it.

Comment: @JoeZ, Oops, I missed that line. Still seems a bit odd, but at least it *is* a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a function which has been superceded by a safer function. But, if you're able to use C++11, consider using the std::chrono library, and use C++11's put_time to do the formatting:

Example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());

    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%d %B %Y")... (your code)
}
```

You might have to play with the formatting to get the result you required. See put_time reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that you are using a deprecated function, i.e. the function you are using is out of date, you should not use it or use a more recent version.  Here the function is "localtime".  Replace this function with "localtime_s".  The _s version has security enhancements compared to the non-_s version.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deprecated function

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx) usage for `localtime_s`
a security enhanced implementation

And to format the date you should be doing something like this :

```
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm ltm;
    errno_t err = localtime_s(&ltm, &now);

    const std::string months[] ={ "January", "Febrauary", "March","April",
                              "May","June","July","August","September",
                                  "October","November","December"};


    std::cout << "Damon Reynolds Tut 1V "
              << ltm.tm_mday << " "
      << months[ltm.tm_mon] 
          << " " << 1900 + ltm.tm_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft would prefer it if you use their functions, which are "safer" but more importantly not portable to OSX and Linux. The solution is given in the error message itself: compile with `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` defined.

The C solution to format a time is `strftime`, the C++ solution is `std::put_time` (see *polkadotcadaver*'s answer.)